# How to determine which view was touched by UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UIScrollView` with subviews and a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

I create the recognizer like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureRecognized:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
```

The view property of `UITapGestureRecognizer` points to the scroll view itself even if the user touched a different view. I need to know if touch went down on the scroll view directly.

Comment: What is self in the code snippet? scrollView? Typically you do [self.whateverViewAspect addGestureRecognizer:] in order to specifically attach gestureRecognizers to parts of views

Comment: try setting the scrollview to be on top of a seperate UIView object? like [viewWtihSCrollviewOnTopOf addSubview:scrollView]; [viewWtihSCrollviewOnTopOf addGestureRecognizer:tgr];

Answer (score 2):

Paul's suggestions are good, but if you don't want (or can't) subclass or become the delegate of the recognizer, there's another way.

You can ask the gesture recognizer for its `locationInView:` and then retrieve the view which that point is on top of with your scrollView's `hitTest:withEvent:` method (defined on UIView). Something like:

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:scrollView];
UIView *touchedView = [scrollView hitTest:location withEvent:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can become either subclass `UITapGestureRecognizer` and add a new ivar to hold this info by overriding the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method something like this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  /*
   * If you wanted you could store a set of all the views to allow
   * for multiple touches
   */
  self.touchedView = [touches.anyObject view];
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Or if you like you can become the delegate for `UITapGestureRecognizer` and store the tapped view as a property in your class by implementing `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`